# Calculating photolysis time of AgF

Tags: thermodynamics, photochemistry

How can I theoretically predict the time needed to photolyze n moles of $\ce{AgF}$? (with UV) (this is not a homework question)

The photolysis of $\ce{AgF}$ requires UV light - but I don't know which wavelength the UV must be at for the optimal photolysis. Then if the wavelength is known I can calculate the energy of one UV photon of a specific wavelength. After that I can calculate the required amounts of photons required for the reaction

I was thinking of this method:

1. First I need to find out which wavelength the UV must be at for the optimal photolysis of $\ce{AgF}$ (How?)
2. Then I need to calculate the amount of energy required for the photolysis of AgF : on wolframalpha I entered this equation: $\ce{2AgF -> 2Ag + F2}$ and it gave me a $\Delta{}H=409.2\:\mathrm{kJ/mol}$

And somehow I must be able to then figure out which lamp I could use and how long I should use it.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bromide#Photosensitivity)? I think it will take a very long time until everything is photolyzed.

Comment: Unless its initially in very thin film, it will take infinitely long as the silver blocks the ultraviolet and you need separate the fluorine and silver otherwise it just will just react again.